# SugarCRM response ordered dict key _hash

Tags: python, sugarcrm

What is

> _hash

that is received with the API request?
My request url,

> url = "https://" + sugar_instance + "/rest/v10/Leads"

Is there a unique user_id for each Lead/Employee/Module in SugarCRM? And if yes, how can I obtain is using a request. I am using Python.

Comment: You're asking a few different questions here. Are you trying to order it by the _hash? Are you trying to get the user_id of the current owner, or created of the record? You say you're using Python but are you looking for the REST endpoint you need to call? Or Python code to call it? This question is very unclear.

Comment: I want to know what "_hash" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different questions within your question. I'll try to answer all of them.

**What is _hash?**

Have a look at this subset of an API response:

```
"modified_user_id": "e8b433d5-5d17-456c-8506-fe56452fcce8",
"modified_by_name": "Reisclef",
"modified_user_link": {
    "full_name": "Administrator",
    "id": "1",
    "_acl": {
        "fields": [],
        "delete": "no",
        "_hash": "8e11bf9be8f04daddee9d08d44ea891e"
    }
},
"created_by": "1",
"created_by_name": "Administrator",
"created_by_link": {
    "full_name": "Administrator",
    "id": "1",
    "_acl": {
        "fields": [],
        "delete": "no",
        "_hash": "8e11bf9be8f04daddee9d08d44ea891e"
    }
},
```

The "_hash" in the above response is a hash of the related acl record, representing the user's access control limits to the record in question.

We can prove this by looking further down my response. You will notice that the hash changes, but is consistent with each object with the same criteria:

```
"member_of": {
    "name": "",
    "id": "",
    "_acl": {
        "fields": [],
        "_hash": "654d337e0e912edaa00dbb0fb3dc3c17"
    }
},
"campaign_id": "",
"campaign_name": "",
"campaign_accounts": {
    "name": "",
    "id": "",
    "_acl": {
        "fields": [],
        "_hash": "654d337e0e912edaa00dbb0fb3dc3c17"
    }
},
```

What we can gather from this is that the _hash is a hash of the _acl object. You can confirm this by looking at include/MetaDataManager/MetaDataManager.php, line 1035.

Therefore, it's not a hash of the user record, it's a hash of the ACL settings of the record.

**Is there a unique user_id?**

Strictly speaking, no, there won't be a unique user id for every record (unless one user only ever created/edited one record).

If you refer back to my first block of JSON, you'll see there are two user relationships:

> modified_user_id

and

> created_by

These indicate what the unique id is of the *user record*, which we can guarantee to be unique (as far as GUIDs are).

**How can I obtain it?**

It's technically already in the request, but if you just wanted to retrieve the created by user id and modified by user id, you can do the call using this:

```
https://{INSTANCE}/rest/v10/{MODULE}?fields=created_by,modified_user_id
```

Comment: I'd be glad if you could check on this question too. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567081/sugarcrm-call-records-rest-api